# XMLRPC slow and weird websites/services

Tags: security, performance, xml-rpc

I have a relatively new wordpress setup ~1mth old after installing NewRelic, I notice it tells me XMLRPC.php is causing slowdown. When I looked at the details I notice its connecting to some weird sites

[image]

Isit safe to disable it? Also how can I know why isit connecting to these. Is the site compromised?